# Volume of a weird shape

Tags: volume, solid-of-revolution

[image]

Here it's a question actually on integration but I simply don't know how to calculate the volume of the cone enclosed between the dotted planes. It might be very trivial but I could get up to the only realisation that it's going to be probably an ellipsoid not a circular area. 
The figure is actually a right circular cone with semi vertical angle alpha.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "between the lines" or "between the planes"? In the latter case: how does the cone axis is directed wrt to the plane normal?

Comment: Between the planes. Well the cone axis is at an angle of alpha wrt plane normal. Oh I forgot to mention it's a right circular cone with semi vertical angle alpha.

Comment: What do you know about this figure?  The picture is incomplete.  A cone cut by a plane indeed produces an elipse.  The area of the elipse is $\pi ab$ where $a,b$ are the semi-major and semi-minor axes.  And the volume of a cone is $\frac 13 \text {base} \times \text {height}.$  Height measured as distance from the plane to the vertex.

Comment: What is the role of the left plane? It seems that it intersects with the cone exactly at its vertex.  Are the planes parallel? What is the distance between them?

Comment: @Doug we can assume the slant height of the cone as l and accordingly make calculations . The formula you mentioned i know that quite well only I don't seem to know how to find the major axis and minor axis of the ellipse. Any help on that?

Comment: @user the left plane indicates the Y axis if you may say so and from the diagram it's clear that the top plane intersects at the vertex of the cone on the right side exactly yes. And yes the planes are of course parallel. Actually the actual question has the facts that it is a right circular cone and slant height l only it has been scribbled over in a very bad way that I couldn't click a pic of that.

Comment: @user AV is yaxis and the dotted lines are parallel to X axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the clarifications from the comments the problem becomes tractable. Especially the fact that the element $AV$ of the cone is perpendicular to the cutting plane will be used.

To find the volume we need first to calculate the area of the cross section of the cone with the plane, which is an ellipse. Without loss of generality we can assume that the cutting planes are perpendicular to the plane of your figure (PoF) and the cone axis lies in the PoF. Let $d$ be the distance between the planes. As it is just a scaling factor we may for simplicity assume $d=1$.

[image]

With this assumption one easily computes
$$\begin{align}
a&=EB=\frac12\tan2\alpha,\\
x&=DE=\frac12\tan2\alpha-\tan\alpha\\
y&=DF=\frac{\tan\alpha}{\cos\alpha}\\
b&=EE'=\frac y{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}
=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sqrt{\cos2\alpha}}
\end{align}
$$

Recalling that the area of an ellipse is $S=\pi a b$ one finally obtains:
$$
V=\frac13Sd=\frac{\pi d^3}6\frac{\tan2\alpha\sin\alpha}{\sqrt{\cos2\alpha}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: You're welcome!